# Choosing randomly all the elements in the the list just once

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

How is it possible to randomly choose a number from a list with `n` elements, `n` time without picking the same element of the list twice. I wrote a code to choose the sequence number of the elements in the list but it is slow:

```
>>>redshift=np.array([0.92,0.17,0.51,1.33,....,0.41,0.82])
>>>redshift.shape
(1225,)
exclude=[]
k=0
ng=1225
while (k < ng):
      flag1=0
      sq=random.randint(0, ng)
      while (flag1<1):
        if sq in exclude:
           flag1=1
           sq=random.randint(0, ng)
        else:
           print sq
           exclude.append(sq)
           flag1=0
      z=redshift[sq]
      k+=1
```

It doesn't choose all the sequence number of elements in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the original list in the same order and don't want to create then `shuffle` a copy, you can use [`random.sample(lst, n)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) for any `n <= len(lst)`:

```
>>> import random
>>> n = 10
>>> random.sample(xrange(n), n)
[4, 6, 5, 2, 3, 7, 9, 0, 1, 8]
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you are already using a numpy array, you may as well use the tools in that package.

You can use [numpy.random.choice](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with `replace=False`. That will only use each element once:

```
>>> redshift=np.array([0.92,0.17,0.51,1.33,0.41,0.82])
>>> np.random.choice(redshift, redshift.size, replace=False)
array([ 0.41,  0.82,  0.17,  1.33,  0.92,  0.51])
```

Since each is only used once, if you try and get more than the array size elements you get a value error:

```
>>> np.random.choice(redshift, redshift.size+1, replace=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1051, in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:8075)
ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'
```

You can also use [np.random.shuffle](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html#numpy.random.shuffle) if you just want to shuffle the array (or a copy) in place:

```
>>> redshift
array([ 0.92,  0.17,  0.51,  1.33,  0.41,  0.82])
>>> np.random.shuffle(redshift)
>>> redshift
array([ 0.41,  0.82,  1.33,  0.51,  0.92,  0.17])
```

Please note that it is significantly faster to keep a numpy array in numpy rather than switch back to a Python data structure for doing something like get a sorted version:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> import random
>>> source=range(1000000)
>>> a=np.array(source)
>>> timeit('np.random.choice(a, a.size, replace=False)', setup='from __main__ import np, a', number=10)
2.971310766064562
>>> timeit('random.sample(list(a), a.size)', setup='from __main__ import random, a', number=10)
14.129850425058976
```

It this test case -- more than 4x faster.

Comment: Thanks. Definitely better than `np.permutation`. The only reason I will leave my answer is that `choice` is a very recent addition to `np.random`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just shuffle the list and iterate through the elements:

```
from random import shuffle

a = list(range(100))

shuffle(a)

>>> print(a)
[5, 82, 96, 66, 47, 62, 49, 86, 55, 4, 21, 94, 34, 46, 10, 32, 83, 13, 25, 24, 58, 74, 14, 43, 18, 42, 56, 23, 52, 36, 15, 60, 79, 29, 0, 72, 38, 88, 41, 85, 57, 69, 30, 45, 70, 31, 84, 63, 92, 48, 68, 22, 40, 59, 95, 11, 39, 78, 89, 64, 6, 20, 91, 37, 61, 28, 71, 12, 8, 19, 1, 98, 50, 97, 26, 53, 73, 17, 16, 87, 33, 9, 99, 90, 93, 81, 7, 44, 65, 80, 54, 51, 67, 27, 3, 2, 76, 77, 75, 35]
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use `np.random.permutation`, if you do not have any space constraints

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
redshift=np.array([0.92,0.17,0.51,1.33,0.41,0.82])  # A subset of your array
perm = rng.permutation(len(redshift))
redshift_perm = redshift[perm]

print redshift
print perm
print redshift_perm

# yields
# [ 0.92  0.17  0.51  1.33  0.41  0.82]
# [0 1 5 2 4 3]
# [ 0.92  0.17  0.82  0.51  0.41  1.33]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use random.sample, from DOCS:

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population
>   sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

Example:

```
from random import sample
my_list = list(range(10))

for value in sample(my_list,len(my_list)):
    print value
```

Comment: your answer is almost the same as the above one. But it works all!